# Uninitialized constant error when include a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Happened on ruby 3.1.2 & rails 7.0.4

module:
app/models/concerns/password_regeneratable.rb

```
module PasswordRegeneratable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def generate_password
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(self.class::DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
    end
  end
end
```

model:
app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include PasswordRegeneratable

  DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 30
end
```

When I try to call User.generate_password it gives me this error:

```
/app/app/models/concerns/password_regeneratable.rb:6:in `generate_password': uninitialized constant Class::DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH (NameError)
Did you mean?  Class::DEFAULT_SETTINGS
```

I want to use module so I can reuse this generate_password method and possible some other methods for other model classes in the future. Is this kind of implementation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
module PasswordRegeneratable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def generate_password
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(self::DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
    end
  end
end
```

In a class method `self` is the class. Thus `self.class` gives you the confusingly named [`Class` class](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Class) since in Ruby classes are instances of Class.

Comment: More importantly, is this implementation considered acceptable? I'm still not really sure how modules and classes work in ruby

Comment: That question is harder to answer. Rolling your own password management / authentication is generally regarded as risky compared to using tried and tested solutions. Its also debatable if you should stack more responsibity onto the model VS having a separate object thats responsible for generating default passwords.